# are there an equivalent of django mixin in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, web-development-server

So, I'm new to Node and I have a background with Django so there is a Mixins you can add to impose certain authorization on your models such as only login users can see this or only the owner of model can edited. Are there any equivalent for that in node or I should right them on my own?

Comment: Node doesn't really offer much in terms of high-level framework features on it's own. Pick a framework (express, koa, fastly, etc) and from there try searching.

Answer (score 0):

```
"https://javascript.info/mixins"
```

EventMixin
An important feature of many browser objects (for instance) is that they can generate events. Events are a great way to “broadcast information” to anyone who wants it. So let’s make a mixin that allows us to easily add event-related functions to any class/object.